# Share a Python executable that uses Google Sheets API without sharing credentials

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to compile an executable file of my Python script without sharing the `credentials.json` file which is required for the Google Sheets API to work? In other words, how can I embed those credentials in the script?

Answer (score -1):

.env files
https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ they will hide the info

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. 
Link-only answers are bad! You should summarize the linked page in your answer here so your answer doesn't become 
useless in case of [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).
[Why is linking bad?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/174780)
| 
[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/174780) 
| 
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)